# Table Row Added with Jquery not included in Request

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a table that you can add a row to with a button:

```
@foreach($criteria as $row)
    <tr>
        <td width="10%" id="Iteration{{ $loop->iteration }}">{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
        <td width="80%">
            <span><input id="Question{{ $loop->iteration }}" name="Question[]" placeholder="Question" class="form-control input-md warning" type="text" value="{{ $row->Question }}"></span>
            <span><textarea id="Description{{ $loop->iteration }}" name="Description[]" placeholder="Description" class="form-control input-md warning">{{ $row->Description }}</textarea>
        </td>
        <td width="10%"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">DELETE</button></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Here is the button logic:

```
 $("#AddRow").click(function(){
    var iteration = parseFloat($("#table tr:last td:first").html());
    if (!iteration)
    {
        iteration = 0;
    }
    var newiteration = iteration + 1;
    $('#table tr:last').after("<tr> <td width='10%' id='Iteration" + newiteration + "'>" + newiteration + "</td><td width='80%'><span><input id='Question" + newiteration + "' name='Question[]' placeholder='Question' class='form-control input-md warning' type='text' value=''></span><span><textarea id='Description" + newiteration + "' name='Description[]' placeholder='Description' class='form-control input-md warning'></textarea></td><td width='10%'><button class='btn btn-danger' type='button'>DELETE</button></td></tr>");
    });
```

This works well, it adds a new row and it looks/functions identically to the existing rows. However, the new rows are not included in the request when it is posted. How is this happening? They are part of the same name: `Question[]` and `Description[]`. Does anybody have any insight?

As requested, here is the full code of the form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('/inspections/bank/records/'.$record->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {!! csrf_field() !!}
   {!! method_field('PUT') !!}
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body">
<form>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 pr-1">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Inspection Name</label>
            <input required id="Name" name="Name" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $record->Name }}">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 pl-1">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Interval</label>
            <select required id="Interval" name="Interval" class="form-control custom-select">
               <option <?php if ("$record->Interval" == "Daily") { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="Daily">Daily</option>
               <option <?php if ("$record->Interval" == "Weekly") { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
               <option <?php if ("$record->Interval" == "Monthly") { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
               <option <?php if ("$record->Interval" == "Yearly") { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Description</label>
            <textarea id="InspectionDescription" name="InspectionDescription" rows="4" cols="80" class="form-control" value="">{{ $record->Description }}</textarea>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <h2>
            <span class="text-capitalize">Items</span>
         </h2>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="AddRow">Add Item</button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <div class="box-body table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-hover table-outline mb-0" id="table">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th width="10%">#</th>
                     <th width="80%">CRITERIA</th>
                     <th width="10%">DELETE</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  @foreach($criteria as $row)
                  <tr>
                     <td width="10%" id="Iteration{{ $loop->iteration }}">{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                     <td width="80%">
                        <span><input id="Question{{ $loop->iteration }}" name="Question[]" placeholder="Question" class="form-control input-md warning" type="text" value="{{ $row->Question }}"></span>
                        <span><textarea id="Description{{ $loop->iteration }}" name="Description[]" placeholder="Description" class="form-control input-md warning">{{ $row->Description }}</textarea>
                     </td>
                     <td width="10%"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">DELETE</button></td>
                  </tr>
                  @endforeach  
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="RecordID" value="{{ $record->id }}">
   <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
        <span class="fa fa-save"></span> &nbsp;
        <span data-value="Submit">Save</span>
    </button>
    </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is your form and how do you do the submit?

Comment: Can you update your answer with full code of `form` tag

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the full code of the form tag.

Comment: You have two opening form tags here.. And first opening and the one closing <form> start/end in the middle of a (different) div.

Comment: This might be an HTML tag problem. You should always care about your opening and closing tag sequences.